# synchronized vs AtomicReference

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, synchronization, mutual-exclusion

I am trying to compose system design in which a module works on shared resource.
So to avoid the data being modified by other concurrent requests, I have few queries related to concurrent requests/thread safety :

**QUESTIONS :**

a) Do I need `synchronized` block if my application is not creating any explicit thread(like Thread/Runnable) but receiving concurrent  HTTP requests ( like a testing tool Load Runner).

b) Is the `AutomicRefrence<BigDecimal>` is a good alternative of synchronized(objectField) block when application is not multi-threaded in nature but processing concurrent HTTP requests.

Comment: What you _usually_ need is `@Transactional`.

Comment: `synchronized` is useless in a server environment, because it only constrains a single copy of your application. Transactions are how you ensure consistency with multiple instances.

Comment: If you have multiple machines accessing the same account id, you can't use synchronized because you can only synchronized within a single JVM. So it will not prevent different JVM's from accessing the same account.

Comment: [This](https://dzone.com/articles/synchronized-by-the-value-of-the-object-in-java) may help.

Comment: Also note that the `toString()` method might create a new String each time so using this for synchronisation is not safe.